# How do I know when an individual request in a curl_multi_exec() has finished in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I would like to time my individual requests. They were timed before as separate curl requests. Now I would like to combine them with `curl_multi_exec` and continue to time how long they take. Here is my code:

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ebayRequest);
curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $prosperentRequest);
$running = null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    curl_multi_select($mh);
} while ($running > 0);
$ebay = curl_multi_getcontent($ebayRequest);
$prosperent = curl_multi_getcontent($prosperentRequest);
//close the handles
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ebayRequest); 
curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $prosperentRequest);
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Here is the old code which timed them.

```
$ebayTime = microtime(true);
// $ebay = $this->ebayExecuteSearch($ebay);
Yii::warning("Ebay time: ".(microtime(true) - $ebayTime));
```

I thought [curl_multi_info_read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-info-read.php) might help, but it doesn't look useful.

Comment: Php is single threaded.a  request is sent only after previous request is finished

Comment: Then what is the point of `curl_multi_exec`? I'm pretty sure the Curl extension allows processing of multiple requests simultaneously.